# how do I stop cpanel from redirecting main domain to subdirectory?

Tags: magento-1.7, cpanel, http-redirect, joomla3.0, vtiger

whenever I type my www.domain.com into the address bar, I automatically get redirected to `www.domain.com/site/index.php.`

I have removed all subdomain links and redirects in cpanel as well as cleared all of the .htaccess files in `/www/` & `/public_html/` and all subdirectories but the problem still remains.

Not sure if there is any other place redirects can exist for this to happen, but what I want is is when I type `www.domain.com`, it goes straight into the `ROOT DIRECTORY` and shows me the directory tree.

Within the main subdirectories I'm using:
Magento 1.7.2
Joomla 3.0
VTiger 5.4

Comment: Check the redirects from the cpanel. open cpanel >> search for redirects. if you are seeing any unwanted redirests, remove it. Also make sure that your index.php in the root directory is not having any redirects in the code. You can check that by using the help of a developer.

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/apache2/sites-available/default 
check for DocumentRoot directives such as

DocumentRoot /var/lib/orangehrm

Also check for rewrite directives.

Comment: UPDATE:

I had a RewriteBase rule in my .htaccess file!
I removed the sub folder option, and now all works good! Sorry for such a late reply